# Wordpress: update all field values?

Tags: wordpress, field

I want to update all field values (of a custom field) to a specific value. Would like to make it like a function and run it on a specific page or when button is clicked.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). A selection of custom keys and their values can be added to WordPress where as the custom keys and values a certain post is assigned is on a per post basis.

EDIT:
Try this [Custom Fields plugin](http://tribulant.com/products/view/7/wordpress-custom-fields-plugin) to see if it helps you administering your fields.

Comment: Thanks. Can i make a function that resets all values (on a specific field) on all posts at the same time?

Comment: No this all seems to be post specific. Although I do remember there being a recent question regarding this and the person who answered did so with some quick SQL that did the job. Try digging a little further around here.

Alternatively you could write a quick script to pull all post ID's, loop through each one, and update keys that way I suppose, but that still may not be the best method.

Comment: You're very welcome. Why I have not come up with a direct method of administering this through code please give the link I have posted in my answer a look to see if it will help you.